# ng:areq Argument 'AppDetailsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, controller, coffeescript

I am trying to link my coffee script file to the appropriate controller but I get the following error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'AppDetailsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/ng/areq?
```

Firstly, i need to click a button to create a new app.

Here is the html:

```
<button id="create-new-app" ng-click="createApp()"/>
```

When I click the button, I need it to trigger a modal dialog.

Here is my coffee script file:

```
$scope.createApp = ->
    $uibModal.open
        templateUrl: 'views/admin/app.html'
        controller: 'AppDetailsCtrl'
        windowClass: 'lg'
        resolve:
            app: ->
                null
            platforms: ->
                $scope.Platforms
            languages: ->
                $scope.Languages
    .result.then (newApp) ->
        console.log "create app #{newApp.Name}"
        $scope.creatingObject.App = true
        payload = angular.copy(newApp)
        $http.put(
            "#{$config.serverAddress}AppStoreAdmin/CreateApp"
            payload
        )
```

And here is my angular controller called app.coffee:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller 'AppDetailsCtrl', (
$scope
$uibModalInstance
store
platforms
languages
) ->

$scope.languages = languages
$scope.platforms = platforms.map (platform) ->
    ID: platform.ID
    Name: platform.Name

if app
    $scope.title = "Edit App"
    $scope.app = app
    $scope.app.AppstorePlatform = $scope.app.AppstorePlatform.ID
else
    $scope.title = "Create App"
    $scope.app = {
        AppstoreStoreLanguages: []
        AppstoreFields: []
    }
```

What am I not seeing here? Any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `angular.module('app.controllers').controller 'AppDetailsCtrl', (` - See the missing bracket after controller ?

Comment: I don't seem to be missing a bracket